# org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- Start expire sessions StandardManager and End expire sessions StandardManager

Tags: tomcat, sticky-sessions, session

I am just a beginner with tomcat and got stuck with following error while deploying a third party application.

I have certainly start getting in tomcat (tomcat version is 7 on windows 2008 r2) logs lot following error and these are happening multiple times in second. Any idea why tomcat is behaving like it? The application I am trying to deploy is also miss behaving.

```
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409080708774 sessioncount 1
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409080708774 sessioncount 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409080708774 sessioncount 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1409080708774 sessioncount 0
2014-08-26 19:18:28,774 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] DEBUG org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase- End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 0 expired sessions: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

These are no erros. These are debugging messages they show correct and expected tomcat behavior and there is virtually nothing you should do about them. If you dont want to see them you need to change logging level in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/logging.properties.

Check this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html for more details.